# Multiple mocks on the fetch with vitest at same time

Tags: vite, vitest

setupAccessToken calls 2 different fetch commands, how can I mock them without splitting that function up?

```js
    global.fetch = vi.fn(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        ok: true,
        text: () => {
          return Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(accessTokenMock_pass));
        },
      })
    ) as Mock;

    await setupAccessToken();
```

I want to set up two of these rules to work concurrently

```js
    global.fetch = vi.fn(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        ok: true,
        text: () => {
          return Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(accessTokenMock_fail));
        },
      })
    ) as Mock;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```js
vi.fn()
  .mockResolvedValueOnce({
    ok: true,
    text: () => {
      return Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(accessTokenMock_pass));
    },
  })
  .mockResolvedValueOnce({
    ok: true,
    text: () => {
      return Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(accessTokenMock_fail));
    },
  })
```

to mock each subsequent call differently. You can also provide a default mock implementation (either directly in the `vi.fn()` argument or using any of the `.mock*Value()`/`.mockImplementation()` functions) which will be overridden by `.mock*Once()` on each of the next calls, before reverting back to that default mock.

See [vitest.dev/api/mock#mockresolvedvalueonce](https://vitest.dev/api/mock.html#mockresolvedvalueonce) for more information.